# How to make a "fat jar" of a Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ I just created a new Maven project and added the following to the pom file http://undertow.io/downloads.html and the following to a Main.java file http://undertow.io/index.html

Now if I run the code all works well, but how do I make this as a "fat jar" that will contain all the dependencies in the pom file and that I'll be able to run by just `java -jar my.jar` ? Like you are able to do with a Spring Boot app.

Comment: Doing this will eradicate the constituent libraries’ manifests, which may contain important information.

Comment: How is this different to making an executable jar with dependencies using maven. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) does this well.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <transformers>
              <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>package.Main</mainClass>
              </transformer>
            </transformers>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: thank you - this works well for me, but it seems to create two jars by default. How can I opt just for the fat one?

Comment: The other jar is created by `maven-jar-plugin`. Is the 2nd jar really in your way?

Comment: well I find it slightly confusing and would be happy to have kind of a simple switch "make fat jar yes/no"

Comment: I think control of the name is the best you're going to get. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088701/maven-shaded-jar-is-prefixed-with-original-in-the-file-name

Comment: @J.Doe Have you figured out how to create 1 file???

Comment: @Axel23 this was 2 years ago!! check for newest versions of all related libs, they keep get improved. At time being 2 years ago I think I got along with 2 files somehow.

Answer (score 6):

1) Add the `Spring-boot-maven-plugin` to the pom.xml file

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

2) Change the packing to jar

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

3) `mvn package` will create the executable jar.

Comment: I like this solution but I think you should consider editing it to remove the version from the plugin and have the pom specify a parent pointing at spring-boot-start-parent.