# Not download/init browser driver when used webdrivermanager-x.x.x.jar (without Maven)

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

For my Selenium/Java project [without Maven], using webdrivermanager-1.7.2.jar in  to automate binary downloads for chromedriver but I'm getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory" message.
My code:

```
package selenium_webdriver_api;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;

public class Topic_29_ManageBrowserVersion {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().version("2.33").setup();
        // Or: ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    }

    @Before
    public void setupTest() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Download the slf4.jar and add to classpath... You should check out the dependencies for this - http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/github/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/2.0.0/webdrivermanager-2.0.0.pom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDriverManager depends on several libraries such as `slf4j-api`, `commons-io`, `gson`, among others (see its [pom.xml](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/pom.xml) for the complete list). If you are using WebDriverManager without the help of a build tool (e.g. Maven, Gradle) you need to resolve these dependencies manually. The other option is to generate a fat jar from the source, for example using the `maven-assembly-plugin` (info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)) or `maven-shade-plugin` (info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089189/how-to-make-a-fat-jar-of-a-maven-project)).

Comment: Hi @Boni García, work well for me. So I have a question more, Can webdrivermanager work with TestNG framework?

Comment: Yes, WebDriverManager can work with TestNG or any other test framework, always in conjunction with Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Thanks you so much!