# How to build a jar in Spring Boot then add it to other projects

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I have a package in one Spring Boot project. The package contains domain objects.

The folder looks like this:

```
IDomainModel
ModelOne
ModelTwo
```

How can I make a jar of only these files then bring it into my other projects. I cannot use artifactory.

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39089189/how-to-make-a-fat-jar-of-a-maven-project

Comment: It's not idiomatic in Java to use the Hungarian-style `I*`.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have used maven.

If you have installed de jar using `mvn install`, then it should be available for all the projects you try to build.

Since `mvn install` puts your compiled jar in your local repository with the groupId, artifactId and version you provided in your pom.xml file. Then you could use that same jar as a dependency in any project with access to your local repository.