# Generate exe with launch4j with maven Project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, launch4j

I have to try generating .exe file Using Maven Project. I get a correct jar with my dependencies but i dont get an exe file. Is there something else to do?.
But it will always showing launch4j exception like,

```
[INFO] Replacing D:\SpiralUpWorkspace\SpiralShareAutoTaskAllocation\target\SpiralShareAutoTaskAllocation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with D:\SpiralUpWorkspace\SpiralShareAutoTaskAllocation\target\SpiralShareAutoTaskAllocation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7.21:launch4j (l4j-clui) @ SpiralShareAutoTaskAllocation ---
[INFO] Platform-specific work directory already exists: C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\net\sf\launch4j\launch4j\3.11\launch4j-3.11-workdir-win32
[ERROR] 
net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException: Application jar doesn't exist.
    at net.sf.launch4j.Builder.build(Builder.java:76)
    at com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j.Launch4jMojo.execute(Launch4jMojo.java:403)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.920 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-29T12:30:13+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/46M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7.21:launch4j (l4j-clui) on project SpiralShareAutoTaskAllocation: Failed to build the executable; please verify your configuration. Application jar doesn't exist. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.spiralshare.autoallocation</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpiralShareAutoTaskAllocation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpiralShareAutoAllocation</name>
  <description>SpiralShare Task Auto Allocation</description>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>

       <!-- Commons -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>gui</headerType>
                        <jar>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}-shaded.jar</jar>
                        <outfile>${project.build.directory}/SpiralShareAutoAllocation.exe</outfile>
                        <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>com.spiralshare.autoallocation.AutoAllocationMain</mainClass>
                            <preCp>anything</preCp>
                        </classPath>
                        <icon>application.ico</icon>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.8</minVersion>
                            <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                            <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                            <copyright>2017 spiraluplabs.com</copyright>
                            <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                            <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                            <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                            <companyName>SpiralUp</companyName>
                            <internalName>SpiralShareAutoAllocation</internalName>
                            <originalFilename>SpiralShareAutoAllocation.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

I did some mistake in my pom.xml file, But I don't know..

Pls, let me know your suggestion..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4088861/5572007

You shouldn't use "-shaded" suffix. 
Quote: "[Shaded plugin] normally renames that jar to target/original-artifact-version.jar, and gives the shaded JAR the name target/artifact-version.jar". You can check your target folder for names of generated jar files.

Answer (score 1):

Check that jar file corresponding to template really exists:

```
${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}-shaded.jar
```

You can replace this template to hardcoded full path to jar file and run build to verify all correct.

Comment: thnks, @Anton Tupy. 
${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}-shaded.jar  
jar will not generated.. let me know any other way..?