# Bundle JRE inside JAR/EXE application

Tags: java, maven, bundle, inno-setup, launch4j

i have a maven project and with launch4j plugin i managed to create the EXE file from it.
The problem is when i run that EXE file into a machine without JAVA it wont start, and i get errors.

I've looked in different places but the answer is always to use "INNO SETUP COMPILER" my question is : Is there any way so that i can deliver to the end user an EXE file and he won't have to install JAVA to run it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate exe with launch4j with maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018943/generate-exe-with-launch4j-with-maven-project)

Comment: i'm generating exe with launch4j as a maven plugin, but my question is about JRE, i could not run my exe in a machine wih no JRE inside

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 9, you could look into `jlink`. I have no time to dig further into this right now, so I'll only post a link, despite Stack Overflow's rules...

Check [this tutorial](https://steveperkins.com/using-java-9-modularization-to-ship-zero-dependency-native-apps/) and [the official reference for `jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm).

Comment: i use maven, and for maven jlink is in prerelease state

Comment: So? Participate in the pre-release phase. Put your energy in trying and testing your app and if it fails, go tell them, and why if you're able to know that info as well... Or you could switch to Gradle, or you could...